# Unable to generate X509Data and X509Certificate tag using Php WS02

Tags: php, x509certificate

Problem in Generating below,when tried with all kinds of inputs in WS02 policy.xml.Kindly assit in generating below part in webservice request.

```
<ds:KeyInfo> 
                <ds:X509Data>
                   <ds:X509Certificate>MIIDUjCCAjqgAwIBAgIIBX96VBJzA1QwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwWjERMA8GA1UEAxMIUEdXU3Vi
    Q0ExEDAOBgNVBAoTB1NpZW1lbnMxEzARBgNVBAcTCkJyYXRpc2xhdmExETAPBgNVBAgTCFNsb3Zh
    a2lhMQswCQYDVQQGEwJTSzAeFw0wNjAxMDQxNTExMzBaFw0wODAxMDQxNTIxMzBaMFsxEjAQBgNV
    BAMTCUNhcm1lblNpbTEQMA4GA1UEChMHU2llbWVuczETMBEGA1UEBxMKQnJhdGlzbGF2YTERMA8G
    A1UECBMIU2xvdmFraWExCzAJBgNVBAYTAlNLMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCc
    rUHuWD+sfU+PS+vYe/wwAOWlpTqpcRhKwXTlhtfekQSEz/jzqWhfRuPzNil16QFOdPZg5M0OusI3
    ln239La5ZpkTSvCc5LrNbj4SvJu2cbc1UYU1BAQCipxs6kG1biYd3nWqpGum8nESybLSPHActZ/1
    DKVauBXEWFSKdazUkQIDAQABo4GeMIGbMAwGA1UdEwEB/wQCMAAwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgWgMDsG
    A1UdJQQ0MDIGCCsGAQUFBwMBBggrBgEFBQcDAgYIKwYBBQUHAwQGCCsGAQUFBwMFBggrBgEFBQcD
    BzAdBgNVHQ4EFgQURQJ7qpFi7doKbZvRkDIf4My3LrIwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUtbaYUw+qe+iV0ruq
    WFVWZDJdB4kwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAI3xvGKw8nsZdyVh29ON+mlfsv2LERT+zqeNSsuE
    Pno58V+HFn28QaPJX7CwNsfRS0txA7gbmAM5BgUPXVWzqjgXp0HeWj1qzM5yuawLzBP9d7thWkrK
    ZOr7vWPMKFkhiw37WFaSot6HGVCU+KrMxL2hteIhLNGKLKQiKVIoUpAKgzuGe9PBwaxD1JxsBSKs
    x8zigoPAlMhRdktg1lYI7/jKgEXPK9TfNmP1bQGErP88j4aw3fC2DQiOaewjQlCV7BaZ5ZdYLlj8
    IV1BmGukpJZvTUj6/T6ui5CrAngiGEL17NNWkvunn4Vrie038D5U3NK31b/uKdMHiwmb1iu/Ykc=</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
                <ds:KeyValue>
                   <ds:RSAKeyValue>
                      <ds:Modulus>nK1B7lg/rH1Pj0vr2Hv8MADlpaU6qXEYSsF05YbX3pEEhM/486loX0bj8zYpdekBTnT2YOTNDrrC
    N5Z9t/S2uWaZE0rwnOS6zW4+ErybtnG3NVGFNQQEAoqcbOpBtW4mHd51qqRrpvJxEsmy0jxwHLWf
    9QylWrgVxFhUinWs1JE=</ds:Modulus>
                      <ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent>
                   </ds:RSAKeyValue>
                </ds:KeyValue>
             </ds:KeyInfo>
```

This $xml , not able to embed in soap headers. $client = new WSClient(array("wsdl"=>"/home/sps_mtnc_dev/Preetham/CBSInterface_BusinessMgr.wsd‌​l", "policy" => $policy, "securityToken" => $xml)). Reult we are not able to see X509 certificate

Answer (score 1):

How is this?:

```
<?php

include('File/X509.php');

$cert = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----';

$x509 = new File_X509();
$x509->loadX509($cert);
$pubKey = $x509->getPublicKey();

$xml = '<KeyInfo><X509Data><X509Certificate>';
$xml.= preg_replace('#-.*-#', '', $cert);
$xml.= '</X509Certificate></X509Data><KeyValue>';
$xml.= $pubKey->getPublicKey(CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_XML);
$xml.= '</KeyValue></KeyInfo>';

echo preg_replace('#(</?)#', '$1ds:', $xml);
```

It uses [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) and requires you provide an X.509 cert.

Comment: Thanks for the info shared, Currently this X509Data and X509Certificate tags are not generating due to the following php script and WS02 policy file

Comment: Well the script I posted works for me. When you say "following php script" are you referring to the one I wrote or one you wrote? And idk what the WS02 policy file is? The script I posted just takes in a PEM and returns an XML based key.

Comment: i pasted the script and policy.xml below

Answer (score -1):

```
Here is the script and policy.xml. Not able to generate formed request in soap request.Kindly assit

<?php

try {

    $my_cert = ws_get_cert_from_file("/home/sps_mtnc_dev/Preetham/keys/bob_cert.cert");

    $my_key = ws_get_key_from_file("/home/sps_mtnc_dev/Preetham/keys/bob_key.pem");

    $rec_cert = ws_get_cert_from_file("/home/sps_mtnc_dev/Preetham/keys/alice_cert.cert");


    /*Load policy file*/
    $policy_xml = file_get_contents("/home/sps_mtnc_dev/Preetham/keys/policy.xml");
    //$policy = new WSPolicy(array("security"=>array("useUsernameToken" => TRUE, "includeTimeStamp" => TRUE)));
    $policy = new WSPolicy($policy_xml);

include('/home/sps_mtnc_dev/wso2/wsf-master/php/scripts/phpseclib0.3.10/File/X509.php');

$cert = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----';

$x509 = new File_X509();
$x509->loadX509($cert);
$pubKey = $x509->getPublicKey();

$xml = '<KeyInfo><X509Data><X509Certificate>';
$xml.= preg_replace('#-.*-#', '', $cert);
$xml.= '</X509Certificate></X509Data><KeyValue>';
$xml.= $pubKey->getPublicKey(CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_XML);
$xml.= '</KeyValue></KeyInfo>';

echo preg_replace('#(</?)#', '$1ds:', $xml);
    $sec_token = new WSSecurityToken(array("privateKey" => $my_key, "certificate" => $my_cert));

    $client = new WSClient(array("wsdl"=>"/home/sps_mtnc_dev/Preetham/CBSInterface_BusinessMgr.wsdl", "policy" => $policy, "securityToken" => $sec_token));
    //$client = new WSClient(array("wsdl"=>"/home/sps_mtnc_dev/Preetham/prov-gw-hlr_subscriber-4.5.3.wsdl"));
    printf("WSDL loaded \n");
    //$client = new WSClient(array("useSOAP" => TRUE,"policy" => $policy,"securityToken" => $sec_token));

    printf("Response = %s \n", $client);
    $proxy = $client->getProxy();
    //printf("Proxy = %s \n",$proxy);

    printf("getProxy done \n");


    $SessionEntity = array("Name" => 10001, "Password" => "qBnsbLtbFeBA1rBaPtuwXg==", "RemoteAddress" => 172123);
    $RequestHeader = array("CommandId" => "NewSubscriber", "Version" => 1, "TransactionId" => 1234, "SequenceId" => 1, "RequestType" => "Event", "SessionEntity" => $SessionEntity, "SerialNo" => 1234);
    $Subscriber = array("Lang" => 1234, "PaidMode" => 1234, "MainProductID" => 1234, "IMSI" => 1234);
    $NewSubscriberRequest = array("SubscriberNo" => 1234, "Subscriber" => $Subscriber);


    printf("Input message ready \n");

    $resMessage = $proxy->NewSubscriber(array("NewSubscriberRequest" => $xml));
    printf("Input message ready = %s \n", $resMessage);
    printf("Response = %s \n", $resMessage->str);

} catch (Exception $e) {

    if ($e instanceof WSFault) {
        printf("Soap Fault: %s\n", $e->Reason);
    } else {
        printf("Message = %s\n",$e->getMessage());
    }
}
?>



policy.xml :

<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="SgnOnlyAnonymous" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2005/xx/oasis-2005xx-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd">
   <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
         <sp:AsymmetricBinding>
            <wsp:Policy>
               <sp:InitiatorToken>
                  <wsp:Policy>
                     <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Always">
                        <wsp:Policy>
                          <sp:RequireKeyIdentifierReference/>
                            <sp:RequireIssuerSerialReference/>
                            <sp:RequireEmbeddedTokenReference/>
                           <sp:WssX509V1Token10/>
                           <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                     </sp:X509Token>
                  </wsp:Policy>
               </sp:InitiatorToken>
               <sp:RecipientToken>
                  <wsp:Policy>
                     <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Always">
                        <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:RequireKeyIdentifierReference/>
                            <sp:RequireIssuerSerialReference/>
                            <sp:RequireEmbeddedTokenReference/>
                        <sp:WssX509V1Token10/>
                           <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                     </sp:X509Token>
                  </wsp:Policy>
               </sp:RecipientToken>
                <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                  <wsp:Policy>
                     <sp:Basic128Rsa15/>
                  </wsp:Policy>
               </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
               <sp:Layout>
                  <wsp:Policy>
                     <sp:Lax/>
                  </wsp:Policy>
               </sp:Layout>

               <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
            </wsp:Policy>
         </sp:AsymmetricBinding>

          <sp:SupportingTokens>
           <sp:Body/>
         </sp:SupportingTokens>
      <sp:SignedParts>
            <sp:Body/>
         </sp:SignedParts>


      </wsp:All>
   </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

Comment: A couple of things. First, this code should probably be included as an edit to your original question instead of as an answer. As is your "answer" is liable to be deleted. That said, I note that you're doing `echo preg_replace('#(</?)#', '$1ds:', $xml);`. Do `$xml = preg_replace('#(</?)#', '$1ds:', $xml);`.

Comment: This $xml , not able to embed in soap headers. $client = new WSClient(array("wsdl"=>"/home/sps_mtnc_dev/Preetham/CBSInterface_BusinessMgr.wsdl", "policy" => $policy, "securityToken" => $xml)). Reult we are not able to see X509 certificate